# How to display a label-field with multiple pieces of data

Tags: layout, labels, page-layout

Let's say I have a details page that lists various pieces of information taken from a form. This works fine when I have a single attachment (link) per field.

However, let's say the user can attach multiple files for a single field. What is the best way to display this information while maintaining consistency with the rest of the form?

**Option 1: List files**

Issue: looks bad with multiple labels of varying lengths (which we definitely have on our site)

[image]

**Option 2: List Under label when multiple links**

Issue: inconsistent with other label-fields, which are inline.

[image]

**Option 3: Inline, separated by commas**
Issue: hard to read. The file names are important for a user to read (they are named after specific documents)

*[No image because I can only post 2 links]*

Any advice on which option is the best (or another option) for readability and consistency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visually I've seen treatments to align the label and the details separately. For example, left align both columns with some spacing between the two columns:

[image]

Or you can right align the label and left align the details:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alignment problem can be solved by this arrangement of labels and fields. But it takes more space, depends on the size of data to enter, otherwise it is an good option in forms.[image]